# Exporting Datas into Other Format in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

In a web page button click event we need to export 2,00,000 to 5,00,000 records into other format [Word, Excel, XML and HTML] using ASP.NET application.

At the time we facing the time out issue? How we can solve this issue? Please guide us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start export as a background task.

In the meantime you will be checking the status of the operation and displaying some animation to the user saying "Your export is in progress, please wait.".

When the export is complete you will update that portion of the page using Ajax and display a message to the user: "You can now access your exported file at this link. It will be there for you during the next 24 hours.".

Comment: Hi Developer Art, Can you please give me link for sample application.